# Values "undefined" from object stored in Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to receive details about a user in my firebase data. I'm using Ionic and Typescript.

I create a user like this

```
addToDatabase(user: User) {
let isInstructor = user.isInstructor == null ? false : user.isInstructor;
this.afDB.list("/users/").push(
  {
    "firstName": user.firstName,
    "lastName": user.lastName,
    "email": user.email,
    "institution" : user.institution,
    "isInstructor": isInstructor
  }
);
}
```

[The user is created as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI6bP.png)

Then retrieve the data like this

```
  async signIn(user: User) {
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then((result) => {

  var ref = this.afDB.database.ref("users/");

  //retrieve values for a single user by email 
  ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.email).once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    var value = snapshot.val();
    console.log(value);
    var firstName = value.firstName;
    console.log(value.firstName);
    var lastName = JSON.stringify(value.lastName);
    console.log(lastName);

    //user.firstName = value.firstName; I want to save user details here
    //user.lastName = value.lastName;  and here for later
  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
  });

  this.shareService.setUserDetails(user); //user detail is shared in the app

  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
}).catch(function (error) {
  alert("Sign in failed:\n" + error.message);
  });
}
```

[This part seems to work fine, I can see the user object in chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHSha.png)

But, when I try to access the object so I can show it in the html later It almost always prints on the page as "undefined"

```
var value = snapshot.val();
console.log(value); //this works fine, shows the object as expected
console.log(value.firstName); //this is what i want! but it's "undefined"
var lastName = JSON.stringify(value.lastName); //trying to stringify
console.log(lastName); //still "undefined"
```

I've tried a lot of other things that's not in displayed in my code here. Just cannot seem to get the data I want.

Update: I've included the JSON export of my DB in case that helps

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-L6JNUj7T9wvssjiWjX9" : {
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "firstName" : "testFirst",
      "institution" : "school-university",
      "isInstructor" : false,
      "lastName" : "testLast"
    }
  }
}
```

Update: Trying to work with promises, this seems to just come back null too.

```
public dataTest(user: User) {
var ref = this.afDB.database.ref("users/");
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  try {
    ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
      if (typeof snapshot.val().firstName === 'undefined') {
        resolve(null);
      } else {
        console.log(snapshot.val().firstName);
        resolve(snapshot.val().firstName);
      }
    })
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e)
  }
});
}

  this.dataTest(user).then(function (result) {
    console.log("result " + result) //this just comes back null
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: with the `console.log(value);` do you see a property "firstName" output?

Comment: Where exactly is your `var value = snapshot.val();` code? Is the `.then` of your call to `ref.orderByChild` guaranteed to have actually completed by the time you are executing `var value = snapshot.val();`? You may be being caught out by the asynchronous nature of the `ref.orderByChild` call, such that the value isn't yet available when you try to access it.

Comment: @PhilipBrack Yes, I see, what looks like to me, the same object from console.log(snapshot.val());

Comment: @AndrWeisR     var value = snapshot.val(); is inside my .then function. I've read a bit about how these asynchronous functions but honestly don't know how to deal with them yet.

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93

Comment: What about if you try `value["firstName"]`?

Comment: @AndrWeisR Same thing, still "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my real issue was not checking for the key that .push generates. I was digging right into the JSON object but skipping the key in the path which what was causing all my values to say "undefined".

So we decided to change how our users are registered. Instead of using .push and generating a key we decided to use the user's email as our key. Firebase doesn't like certain characters being put into keys so we have a small bit of code that removes those special characters and stores the key and then we compare against that to identify specific user data. Probably not the most elegant design but we're students and just trying to figure things out.

The new function to add user data to Firebase:

```
addToDatabase(user: User) {
if (!user.isInstructor) {
  this.afDB.list("users/students/").set(
    user.email
        // Remove disallowed characters from key
        .replace('.', '')
        .replace('#', '')
        .replace('$', '')
        .replace('[', '')
        .replace(']', ''),
    {
      "firstName": user.firstName,
      "lastName": user.lastName,
      "email": user.email,
      "institution" : user.institution,
      "isInstructor": user.isInstructor
    }
  );
} //more repetitive code if a user is a instructor below this
```

The new signIn function that find's a user's data, identifies who they are and then retrieves their data, stores it in a user object and sends it to our share service where the whole app can use the data.

```
async signIn(user: User) {
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then((result) => {
  var usersRef = this.afDB.database.ref("users/");
  // Find user in database
  this.afDB.database.ref("users/students").child(
    user.email
      .replace('.', '')
      .replace('#', '')
      .replace('$', '')
      .replace('[', '')
      .replace(']', ''))
        .once("value", function(snapshot) {

    // Get all user info
    user.firstName = snapshot.child("firstName").val();
    user.lastName = snapshot.child("lastName").val();
    user.email = snapshot.child("email").val();

  }).then((result) => {
    this.shareService.setUserDetails(user);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  });
}).catch(function (error) {
  alert("Sign in failed:\n" + error.message);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this. This code will work for sure.

```
var ref = this.afDB.database.ref("users/");
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.email).once("value", (items : any) => 
{
    console.log("Key: ",items.key);
    console.log("Value: ",items.val());

    let users : any = [];

    items.forEach((item) =>
    {
        users.push({
            key           : item.key,
            firstName     : item.val().firstName,
            lastName      : item.val().lastName,
            email         : item.val().email,
            isInstructor  : item.val().isInstructor
        });
    });
    console.log("All Users : ",users);
    this.userData = users;
});
```

Comment: This "works" but it really doesn't help me. I can already see the data as a JSON object, which is what i want. The problem is when I access that object every property is "undefined".

Comment: Where do you want access? On html page?